# Add cell alasql

Tags: export-to-excel, angular-ui-grid, alasql

How I can add a cell above the headboard ?
Thank you, great job

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nex6K.jpg)

My intention is to put multiple cells above the table using materials alasql

Comment: I have solved , putting all title , and separating jumping line , did not know you could get inside the html title . Resolved.